# Diffrence in number of installs in google console and analytics,is it common or is there something wrong?

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play, app-store

I have published my first game on play store a few days back. I have also implemented google analytics to track number of installs and screens.
But from the day one there is a huge difference between analytics numbers and play store download counts.

I know they take 24 hours to update but even after 24 hrs my stats in developer console were way behind analytics.

And juat today my app went from 10+ downloads (which was also incorrect) to 0+ downloads.

While the google analytics still ahow above 270 active users.

What is wrong? I have tried testing analytics data in real time,they are perfect.
Here is my app:
Crane Runner-
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kamlax.cranerunner.android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there seems to be a problem with Google Play download numbers.

For instance, King of Thieves which has over 200 000 ratings appears to have only 1-5 downloads:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zeptolab.thieves.google

Comment: Well the download counts are now back to the previous number but still incorrect. Is this how play store rolls? Thank you for any help

Comment: August 2021 I have a mobile app campaign running in Google Ads reporting that I have paied for 130 installs on a given day, at the same time Google Play Console reports that I have 120 new installs on that day. I feel like I get ripped of by Google Ads.